# how send Printer command to EPSON LQ-300+ from VB.NET 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, epson, dot-matrix

I have to send a priter command for changing font from VB.NET.

And i am using RawprinterHelperClass and sendstringtoprinter(printername,stringname) function to print a string.

I have Printer Command but i donot know to send it. Printer Command is

[image]